# image is not refreshing in pygame

Tags: pygame

I am learning pygame. I was playing with the code catanimation.py which comes with the pygame example. In this code, If I remove the line DISPLAYSURF.fill(WHITE), it draws multiple images (i.e. it does not refresh). What is the reason? Do I have to make surface white to refresh the image?

Thanks.

Comment: I found that I need to update the background (either filling it or setting background image) also. So, I need to put this line (either filling the background or setting background image) inside the main event loop. I wounder why it does not work if set the surface color/background just one time outside the main event loop.

Comment: It's because every frame (in the loop) it runs part of the loop, therefore if you have your player picture in the loop and the background out, the player will refresh and not the background.

Comment: Sounds logical, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

think of the surface as a drawing canvas. it is going to blit upon your already used canvas, leaving something similar to a trail behind moving objects. filling the screen with white(or any color) will get drawn over the previous frame such that it is no longer visible.